# AMD 7800XT GPU passthru Virt-manager Ubuntu 22.04LTS dont properly work

Tags: drivers, kvm-virtualization, amdgpu, qemu, virt-manager

**Intro:**

Hello,
I have two GPUs, one NVIDIA 3060 and a AMD 7800XT. I would like to have the nvidia to the host itself, and passthru the amd GPU to a W11 VM in virt-manager. I have already did the passthru, but just showing what i went thru.

**Finding GPU, Passthru and enabling IOMMU**

I started with enabling IOMMU in UEFI and checking it working properly, and it does. Also finding the PCIe address for the AMD GPU, and take notes of it to paste in default grub

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:747e] (rev c8)
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:ab30]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:ab30]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
```

(here would it original stand "amdgpu" in "kernal driver in use:")
Here are the /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on iommu=pt vfio.pci.ids=1002:747e,1002:ab30"
```

And rebooted.

All in all IOMMU works and the passthru.

**Fixing GPU host takeover:**

Now i made and edited /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf file.

```
options vfio-pci ids=1002:747e,1002:ab30
softdep amdgpu pre: vfio-pci
```

After that i ran:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And rebooted.

Proof that i did it right:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:747e] (rev c8)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:05fd]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:ab30]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:ab30]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

**Virt-Manager**

Chipset and firmware and pcie passthru:

Chipset: Q35

Firmware: UEFI x86_64: /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.fd

Passing thru the sound and vga from AMD 7800 XT

(i did all the things with setting up the VM and Windows 11 standard installation with PRO)

**In the W11 VM**

Everything works fine and i continue installing the virtio driver..
After that i reboot just to be extra secure.

**Now i install the AMD GPU driver i need.**

I install the amdsoftware installer and run it.
[First error running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbGGF.png) I just press ok and continue.

Now it comes up recommended driver (AMD Radeon RX 7800 XT), i just click ok and continue.

[Second error when after start download driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PSyK.png), i just press ok and it will run and start downloading.

[After driver finish downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqqZW.png), now it stands that i have no problem with the driver and everything is okay, but if i physically plug the GPU HDMI to one of the screens, its just a black screen... Also if i restart the VM now [The GPU will indicate a error code 43](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHMWf.png)

[Also this stands here with the adrenaline software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNqkW.png)

**Things i tried:**

1. First thing i tried is to passthru the NVIDIA card with the same method. That work flawless, but the AMD card is better.
2. I followed [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/16eugoo/does_the_7800xt_7700xt_support_vfio/?rdt=65018) (remember to press "see more replies")

The link was to a howto guide for providing ROM file and how to bypass video card driver detection.

**Conclusion**

I tried searching the whole time for solution but i actually dont know what to do now, but i am mostly certainly that there is a detection type shit on the newer AMD GPU for VM, because of the success of NVIDIA passthru, and i remember i readed something that is was working with a older version of AMD GPUs.So i probally have to make a bypass of some type, but i dont really know where to start.

I would really like any help i could get. If something is unclear or bad explained please comment so i can improve it.

Thank You for your attention.